# Limit of work items in OpenCL is not matching the theoretical limit of CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS. What is happening?

Tags: c, gpu, opencl, nvidia

I have been working with OpenCL for a few months now and recently came across an issue regarding the maximum number of work items (global size) in a particular program that I developed.

First of all, let me go through the working sizes checklist:

1. The kernel I am running is one-dimensional.
2. The local work group size is set to CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE. I also made sure that I can safely use this work size group since nearly no local memory is used.
3. The local work group size always divides the global item size.

Ok, now into the problem. The thing is that my one-dimensional kernel finishes execution with `error code -36` (which is `CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE`) if and only if the number of work items (global item size) is above 2^31 (I add the work group size so to be above 2^31 but still a multiple). Now the first thing I do when I run my program is to check that `CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS` is 64 bits. See below along with some more information that I extract at the beginning of the program:

```
Device [3]: GeForce GTX 980
    Profile      : OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
    is available?: 1
    Global mem   : 4234280960 (4038 MB)
    Local mem    : 49152 (48 KB)
    Compute units: 16
    Max work group size: 1024
    Work size items: (1024, 1024, 64)
    Address space in bits: 64
```

In case you are wondering, this is an application that computes a lot of small jobs. I already devised a solution to skip this, which is assign more work to each work item so that there are less work items. However, I am interested in why this is happening. As far as I know, it should not happen since the address space is 64 bits. I have also made sure that all variables in the program are 64 bits and that it is not getting truncated in any way. Just in case, the variables are:

```
size_t global_item_size;
```

Which I also print during the execution like this to make sure it contains the appropriate value:

```
fprintf(stdout, "Work items: %"PRIu64"\n", (uint64_t) global_item_size);
```

Finally, the kernel receives the number of work items as a parameter inside a struct, which is also 64 bits:

```
 ulong t_work_items;
```

I can not think of any reason to fail, when the address space is 64 bits and all variables that handle the number of work items (2^31 + WORK_GROUP_SIZE) are also 64 bits.
However, I am assuming this is possible. Actually I have not been able to find a reference from anybody else (nor in the documentation) having executed kernels with a higher number of work items without failing.

In particular, I do not need it to work since as I said I can just increase the job size per work item. However I wanted to measure performance depending on three values (job size per work item and work group size) and came across this.

Thank you for your time reading into this!

## EDIT1:

I have also checked `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES` and got `Max work item sizes: (1024,1024,64)`. However, I believe this is not what limits the number of work items since according to the documentation [OpenCL reference](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html):

> The values specified in global_work_size cannot exceed the range given by the sizeof(size_t) for the device on which the kernel execution will be enqueued. The sizeof(size_t) for a device can be determined using CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS in the table of OpenCL Device Queries for clGetDeviceInfo. If, for example, CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS = 32, i.e. the device uses a 32-bit address space, size_t is a 32-bit unsigned integer and global_work_size values must be in the range 1 .. 2^32 - 1. Values outside this range return a CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES error.

I do not get a `CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES` error since my address space is 64 bits. What could be wrong?

Comment: What is the `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES` device property for your device?

Comment: It is `Max work item sizes: (1024,1024,64)`. However I believe this is not what limits the number of global work items, as in the documentation it says that the values specified in global_work_size cannot exceed the range given by the `sizeof(size_t)` for the device on which the kernel execution will be enqueued (which is 64 bits, therefore 2^64-1)

Comment: I think your latter assumption is very optimistic. The address bits just tell you about the addressable *memory* and the size of a pointer.

Comment: You are correct in Edit 1. CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES and CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE are both related to local work sizes, and are not the limits of global work size. It's stated in the documentation of clEnqueueNDRangeKernel in "local_work_size" parameter description.

It's possible you have a bug somewhere else, or you've simply hit a bug in Nvidia's OpenCL implementation. Not the first one and certainly not the only one...

Comment: I really do not think that it is a bug hidden somewhere else because (1) I have tested this program thoroughly, (2) if there was a bug, it could be a result of something like the global id (one dimensional kernel) going out of range; however the number of work items correspond to the size of the array (and actually it is accessed via the global id), (3) the fact that it is just above 2^31 is very suspicious, while all my variables are 64 bits.
So far I have never encountered a bug! I will try to report this. Thanks for the help.